# stream the records returned by query method of waterline(orm for node js)

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I am developing a backend using `node.js`. I am using the `sails.js` framework. Sails uses the waterline adapter for talking to databases. 
In Sails, If we have any Model, then we can directly stream the records like this:

```
Model.stream().pipe(res);
```

But, Now I have table in db, which doesn't have any Model corresponding to that table(basically its a view). So, for getting records from table, I directly use raw query like this:

```
Model.query('select * from transactions',(err, results) => {
 //Now I want to stream those results
 results.stream().pipe(res);
});
```

I have to stream those records in response stream. The above method gives me error`(results.stream is not a function)`. What else I can try to stream those results

Comment: i dont think that you can stream this because waterline returns raw results

Comment: But I have to stream those results, it is not possible to send all records at once

Answer (score 0):

You can use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/streammagic to convert your array to Stream

```
var myArray = ['hello', 'world'];
var myStream = myArray.toStream();

myStream.on('data', function(data){
// The data event will fire twice. Data will contain 'hello' the first time,  'world' the second.
});
```